# Unable to replace files in request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an odd one.. I add an audio file, which is an existing file in the request

```
$file = $request->file('file')[0];
$request->files->add(['audio' => $file]);
```

When I do `dd($request->files->all())` I see newly added `'audio'` element. However when I do `dd($request->allFiles())` I see original array.

I have even added a replace method for files to the `Illuminate\Http\Request` to replace `$files` with no luck.

```
public function replaceFiles($files) {
    $this->files = $files; 
}
```

Am I missing something?

It is as if `$request->files` and `$this->files` within `$request` are two different things.

---

Just noticed that the problem is with `$this->convertedFiles` within `Illuminate\Http\Request` which can be resolved by changing `allFiles()` to something similar to

```
/**
 * Get an array of all of the files on the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function allFiles()
{
    $files = $this->files->all();

    return $this->convertedFiles && count($this->convertedFiles) == count($this->files->all())
                ? $this->convertedFiles
                : $this->convertedFiles = $this->convertUploadedFiles($files);
}
```

---

I've decided to extend `App\Http\Requests\Request` with adjusted `allFiles()` that I have mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge function to add new data into the request object.

```
$request->merge(['index_name' => $variable]);
```

Comment: Not sure if we are talking about the same thing, merge() deals with input source and doesn't handle $_FILES global.